# how to update tabular textboxes value onblur event and saved to database

Tags: javascript

Using ASP.NET MVC 5

I have employees particulars in tabular form.
I want to update the cell number of the employees so that I populate that number in TextBox in Table Cell `<td>`..
how can I save that number to datatbase when onblur event fire...

Script Code is as:::

```
$("#Mobile").blur(function UpdateEmployeeMobile() {
      var MobileNo = $("#Mobile").val();    
      var EMPLOYEEID = $("#StudentID").val();    
      var ID = EMPLOYEEID + "-" + MobileNo;    
      $.post("/Employee/UpdateMobile/" + ID, null, function (data) {    
     });    
 });
```

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: <td><input class="hidden" id="EMPLOYEEID" name="EMPLOYEEID" type="text" value="@item.ID"  />
                      
                        <input id="Mobile" name="Mobile" type="text" value="@item.Mobile" />

Comment: <td><input class="hidden" id="EMPLOYEEID" name="EMPLOYEEID" type="text" value="@item.ID"  />
                        <input id="Mobile" name="Mobile" type="text" value="@item.Mobile" />

Comment: It's not enough. Can you save the whole table in http://jsfiddle.net/